# The continuous stream of [contiguous] questions is contagious

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contiguous) tag does not seem to be a very useful one. It is currently used in 106 questions, has 0 watchers, and no tag wiki description.

---

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is *in most cases* used referring to something like "contiguous memory blocks" or "contiguous arrays". Some uses are rather conceptual/theoretical, as it "contiguous sequences of numbers". Some special cases are where people are asking about specific SQL queries or "contiguous cells" of a table in a UI.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

There are aspects that are certainly on-topic - mainly the "contiguous memory/arrays" part. Even a UI-related question about "contiguous table cells" can be on-topic, but considering the next point...:

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not really. There are no watchers for the tag, which is understandable, because you can hardly consider yourself to be "an expert in contiguous". The most prominent use is that of "contiguous memory". But in these cases, the underlying question could be described more generally (and at the same time more precisely) as being a question about [memory-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-layout).

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

While the meaning in "contiguous memory", "contiguous numbers" or "contiguous table cells" is technically the same, the implications for the question content are totally different.

---

Additionally, there is quite some confusion between [contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contiguous) and [continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous) (and not being a native english speaker, I had to look up the [difference between contiguous and continuous](https://writingexplained.org/contiguous-vs-continuous-difference), admittedly).

<sup>(As a side note: The tag wiki of [continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous) refers to random variables, which may be a bit too narrow, but broadening the meaning could make it another burnination candidate...)</sup>

Some questions are asking about one and tagged with the other, and some questions are simply tagged with *both* the [contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contiguous) and [continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous) tag.

Comment: Your title leaves us hanging between contentment and contention.

Comment: Only 106 questions.  Should be a cinch to burninate.

Comment: The contiguous continuity of the continuum is contagious

Comment: To be continued?

Comment: the contretemps of incontinence? or contourné?

Comment: Shouldn't the contiguous tag be added to this own question?

Comment: The comment thread seems to be contaminated by cont*s.